# How to tell JQuery's DateTimePicker in which local timezone the date is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, timezone

I have a website where I display timeline on which a I'd like to show several events and the "now position". Events are represented by JQuery's DateTimePickers which display dates in server's local timezone (timezone can change for example 2 times a year beacuse of daylight savings, so in my case, dates can be displayed in UTC+1 and UTC+2). The problem is that when a I call `getDate()` on DateTimePicker it assumes that the date stored in DateTimePicker is in UTC timezone and this behaviour causes that "now position" is displayed in wrong position (relative to other events). I thought about sending timezone offset to javascript by django server but the offset isn't always correct for all dates. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Is there a way to tell DateTimePicker in which timezone in tz format the date is? I'd prefer displaying dates in server local timezone not in UTC.